# mysql-proxy got error which cause it to crash

Tags: proxy, mysql

I got that message and i dont know what it is means:

```
Oct 21 12:24:26 lex mysql-proxy: 2013-10-21 12:24:26: ((error)) last message repeated 98 times
Oct 21 12:24:26 lex mysql-proxy: 2013-10-21 12:24:26: ((error)) network-mysqld-packet.c.596: COM_(0x04) should not be (OK|ERR|NULL), got: 00
Oct 21 12:24:26 lex kernel: [4163416.207121] mysql-proxy[14271] trap int3 ip:7ff96e8a4313 sp:7fffb9086ad0 error:0
```

Any idea what can be the cause of it ?

Comment: You should first contact the software developers. That looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the cause it is when somebody connect to the proxy via telnet and close the session incorrectly.